# Problem 4 of Section G of Chapter 13 of Pinter's Book of Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

**First, some background info/context:**

Let $G$ be any group of order $10$. Then, by Cauchy's Theorem, there are elements $a, b \in G$ such that $\text{ord}(a)=2$ and $\text{ord}(b)=5$. Since $\text{ord}(a)$ and $\text{ord}(b)$ are coprime, no power of $a$ is equal to any power of $b$, except for the identity. Thus

$G = \{e, a, b, b^2, b^3, b^4, ab, ab^2, ab^3, ab^4 \}$.

**The problem in the book:**

"If $ba=ab^2$, prove that $ba^2=a^2b^4$ **and conclude that $\textbf{b}=\textbf{b}^{\textbf{4}}$**. This is impossible because $b$ has order $5$; hence $ba \ne ab^2$."

**I don't understand:**

I'm not sure how to prove the bold part, "conclude that $b=b^4$". How does one get this from the previous two equations? Wouldn't you have to assume commutativity somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathrm{ord}(a)=2$ implies that $a^2=1$, and so $ba^2 = b\cdot 1 = b$, and $a^2b^4 = 1\cdot b^4 = b^4$.

Comment: Oh, wow- I can't believe I missed that! haha... I will accept your answer in 6 minutes, after the minimum waiting time expires.